# Problem creating view points

Tags: qgis, geometry, visibility

I have to create view points in order to do a simple intervisibility analysis. However, when I run it, I get this message: [image]

I tried fixing the geometry, as there seems to be a null geometry somewhere, so I ran the fix geometry tool and used this new layer instead. It still gives me the same message. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases `fix geometries` or `check validity` do not find the NULL geometries. I cant tell why, but here is a workaround how I was able to remove these NULL-geometry-features in a similar case as yours:

Create a new attribute containing geometry information like `$x` using field calculator. Then search your attribute table for empty columns in this field. Select the features and delete them manually.